# Plural of title of form name

Tags: grammatical-number

I am writing a letter referencing a document title. I have several of the same document that I need to include the title of the documents in the letter. Do I write "please find six Form 2322" or "please find six Forms 2322"?

Comment: "six copies of Form 2322" would seem to solve the problem nicely

Comment: Never pluralize such names, if only to avoid confusion. The conventional way to write this would be *six of Form 2322*, or *six numbers Form 2322* (using a separate noun).

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the phrases “Please find six Form 2322” or “Please find six Forms 2322” is suitable, the first because of an unsuitable singular, and the latter a missing specifier.  Kate Gregory's suggestion, “...six copies of Form 2322” is usable, and Kris's of “...six of Form 2322”, a little less so.  The form I suggest is “Please find six each Form 2322” (or perhaps “Please find six each of Form 2322”) with the word *each* separating the count from the item description.

Comment: This is correct, but it sounds strange to me, and I think quite a few people would agree. Especially for "please find six each Form 2322." I think "...six copies of Form 2322" is very clear and flows nicely.

Comment: @Ben, I agree that “...six copies of Form 2322” flows nicely.  But standard wording for listing items in an order in a telex or twx used to be a format like "Q ea. D @ P" where Q is a numeric quantity, D is an item description, and P is a price.  It is possible that format has faded from use.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to point out that last part. I don't think many people use it, so if you say it in a conversation, people might look at you funny. It could probably pass in formal writing to put "..six each Form 2322."

Comment: Indeed, if I heard "six each of X" I would absolutely expect it to be followed by "and Y". Otherwise, "each" is superfluous.